# ZF2 - How to do use the order by and the or

Tags: zend-framework2, resultset

I have a new question for you. :)

Do you know how I can add the "order by user_id" in my statement ?
And how I can add an "or" operator ?

```
public function fetchAll()
{
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
    return $resultSet;
}
```

Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A valid procedure is

```
$resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) {
        $select->order('user_id DESC');
});
```

don't forget to declare `use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;` in your PHP file

other informations you can get from here

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.db.table-gateway.html

Comment: my pleasure - don't forget to mark it as answere if it answere your question

Comment: How I can make that ?

Comment: Hooo it's easy... :) ! Thanks you for all